# Convert.ToInt32 in C#

Tags: c#

My problem is, when I want to convert `(result[i].JobOrder)` to int.I have a string 120100 in `(result[i].JobOrder)`. In return I get not integer but something  like "0x0001d524". And I could not understand why.

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(result[i].JobOrder) > maxJobOrder)
    {
        maxJobOrder = Convert.ToInt32(result[i].JobOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like an int. Turn off hex display.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code works, but you have set your debugger to display integers in hexadecimal. The value 0x0001d524 is the hexadecimal representation of the integer 120100.

This is not an error in the program, but a configuration option for your IDE. If you use Visual Studio, you can change this setting by pressing the "Hex" button in the "Debug" toolbar.

[image: Hex button]

---

<sub>As an aside, if you are using C# 3 or newer you can simplify your code by using the [`Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031) method to find the maximum instead of looping:</sub>

```
maxJobOrder = result.Max(x => int.Parse(x.JobOrder));
```

Comment: +1, Great answer! And may I add, that you might want to save JobOrder as a number in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use
    Int32.TryParse
see
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: I thought it could be the solution, but it is not obviously.

Answer (score 1):

try to replace `Convert.ToInt32` with `int.parse()`

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use int.parse is slightly flawed.

**int.parse** will throw one of the following exception whenever it fails. And it only accepts strings as input to convert.

```
ArgumentNullException
FormatException 
OverflowException
```

**Convert.ToInt32** will throw one of the following exceptions whenever it fails. In addition, 
it allows passing of null values, however this means that it returns a 0 as the output value, and it also handles multiple datatypes to be converted into an integer.

```
FormatException 
OverflowException
```

**int.TryParse** will not throw any exceptions, however, it will return a 0 as the output value as the method returns false, and it only accepts strings as input to convert.

You should choose the right tool for the job to prevent any issues in the integrity of your solution.